# How to paging with caml query

Tags: caml-query, paging

I have 10 items with ID from 1 to 10 and set **order by** on **Created** field **Ascending='FALSE'**. **Row Limit** is 3. I use **SPListItemCollectionPosition** for pagination to limit the number of returned items.
First query, I get only 3 items, namely 10, 9 and 8 in order. Second, I need to get expected items, namely 7, 6 and 5, but I get incorrect results.

I have read some articles that tell me to use the syntax, that I pass ID of the first second results set and its value of sort field, **Created** field, like:

```
Paged=TRUE&p_FSObjType=0&PagedPrev=TRUE&p_Created=20150818 07:02:48&p_ID=7
```

However, the query returns items with id 4, 3 and 2?

I also use the syntax `"Paged=TRUE&PagedPrev=TRUE&p_Created={0}&p_ID={1}"` but the result is still wrong.
As far as I understand here is that the query gets items, start from the first item on the list (ID=1) and get only three items, which is set by row limit, and then sort them by **Created** field.

Some tell me that I could capture the first and the last item of the results etc, but in my case, I only have one way backward.

Please give me advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Similar Question
[Paging](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153594/sharepoint-2013-jsom-paging-the-prev-page-button-gives-error-request-failed). You can get the nextPagingInfo using OOTB function

```
nextPagingInfo = spItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition().get_pagingInfo();
```

You need to frame the prevPagingInfo and "Created" doesn't work for sorting. Use "Created_x0020_Date" instead.You can get the Original Source Code form [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92/sourcecode?fileId=92627&pathId=789885789). I used angular with this function and works very well.

Comment: The code I used is SOM, and it did not work properly. I then have to use CSOM, and it works. Thanks again, sekhar.

Comment: See also: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245754(v%3Doffice.15)