# SharePoint 2013 JSOM Paging - The Prev Page Button gives error - Request Failed.Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 undefined

Tags: jsom, paging

I am using SP 2013 JSOM for paging and sorting the list data in `<table>`. I have referred the code from this link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92/sourcecode?fileId=92627&pathId=789885789
The problem is when I am using `sortColumn` as `Created` and click on the Previous Page button (`btnBack`) of paging, then it throws error `Request Failed.Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 undefined`

But for any other column it works fine.

Is it because it is Date/Time column ?

```
var context, 
    web, 
    spItems, 
    position, 
    nextPagingInfo, 
    previousPagingInfo, 
    listName = 'ContactsList', 
    pageIndex = 1, // default page index value 
    pageSize = 4, // default page size value 
    list, 
    camlQuery, 
    sortColumn = 'Created'; // this is sort column, you can add more than one column, but you should add it also to CAML Query & managePagerControl function 

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model  
$(document).ready(function () { 
    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName); 
    camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 

    $("#btnNext").click(function () { 
        pageIndex = pageIndex + 1; 
        if (nextPagingInfo) { 
            position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition(); 
            position.set_pagingInfo(nextPagingInfo); 
        } 
        else { 
            position = null; 
        } 

        GetListItems(); 
    }); 

    $("#btnBack").click(function () { 
        pageIndex = pageIndex - 1; 
        position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition(); 
        position.set_pagingInfo(previousPagingInfo); 
        GetListItems(); 
    }); 

    GetListItems(); 
}); 

function GetListItems() { 
    //Set the next or back list items collection position 
    //First time the position will be null 
    camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position); 

    // Create a CAML view that retrieves all contacts items  with assigne RowLimit value to the query 
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" + 
                                "<ViewFields>" + 
                                       "<FieldRef Name='FirstName'/>" + 
                                       "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + 
                                       "<FieldRef Name='Company'/>" + 
                                  "</ViewFields>" + 
                               "<Query>" + 
                                    "<OrderBy>" + 
                                      "<FieldRef Name='" + sortColumn + "' Ascending='true' />" + 
                                    "</OrderBy>" + 
                               "</Query>" + 
                               "<RowLimit>" + pageSize + "</RowLimit></View>"); 

    spItems = list.getItems(camlQuery); 

    context.load(spItems); 
    context.executeQueryAsync( 
            Function.createDelegate(this, onSuccess), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, onFail) 
        ); 
} 

// This function is executed if the above OM call is successful 
// This function render the returns items to html table 
function onSuccess() { 

    var listEnumerator = spItems.getEnumerator(); 
    var items = []; 
    var item; 

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) { 
        item = listEnumerator.get_current(); 
        items.push("<td>" + item.get_item('FirstName') + "</td><td>" + item.get_item('Title') + "</td><td>" + item.get_item('Company') + "</td>"); 
    } 

    var content = "<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Company</th></tr><tr>" 
                + items.join("</tr><tr>") + "</tr></table>"; 
    $('#content').html(content); 

    managePagerControl(); 
} 

function managePagerControl() { 

    if (spItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition()) { 
        nextPagingInfo = spItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition().get_pagingInfo(); 
    } else { 
        nextPagingInfo = null; 
    } 

    $("#pageInfo").html((((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize) + 1) + " - " + ((pageIndex * pageSize) - (pageSize - spItems.get_count()))); 

    previousPagingInfo = "PagedPrev=TRUE&Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + spItems.itemAt(0).get_item('ID') + "&p_" + sortColumn + "=" + encodeURIComponent(spItems.itemAt(0).get_item(sortColumn)); 

    if (pageIndex <= 1) { 
        $("#btnBack").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } 
    else { 
        $("#btnBack").removeAttr('disabled'); 
    } 

    if (nextPagingInfo) { 
        $("#btnNext").removeAttr('disabled'); 
    } 
    else { 
        $("#btnNext").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } 

} 

// This function is executed if the above call fails 
function onFail(sender, args) { 
    alert('Failed to get items. Error:' + args.get_message()); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Created" returns a Date Object, you cannot use it for sorting. It adds [Object Object] into your pagingInfo string, Use "Created_x0020_Date" instead, it returns string and works perfectly, I ran into the same problem and using "Created_x0020_Date" fixed the issue

```
sortColumn = 'Created_x0020_Date';
```

or do `.toISOString()` on date object and then add to prevPagingInfo

Comment: Is this a custom column(calculated) or default because when I used it, the code throws error : `Field with name "Created_x0020_Date" was not found`

Comment: It is an OOTB column, I wonder why it is not on your list, It may have different name on your list.

Comment: you can format the date value to SharePoint date format, I'm not sure what the format is, but the actual problem is you are trying to add [Object] to String, So try to format the date value, Or use any other calculated column / Modified

Comment: or you can debug how the OOTB get_nextPaginInfo() value returned and form prevPaginInfo it in the same way.

Comment: I converted the `Created` date object to ISO string using `item.get_item('Created'). toISOString()` and it worked fine

Comment: As you said I also checked nextpagingInfo variable and there also the date is in UTC format.... Thanks for your help

Comment: glad it helped!